# mySQL - Querying a field from another table with the same id as in the current one

Tags: php, mysql, sql

This is a quite complex project having specific reasons for the way it is setup, but for ease of learning purposes, I've replaced the subject with just names.

For example, I have two tables:

**Servers**  (stores unique server names)

- server_id (unique id)
- server_name

**Clients** (stores all the clients in the company)

- `server_id` (matches the unique id from `servers` table)
- .. other columns

What I'm trying to do is list the distinct server names from the first table, along with the number of clients that use each server id.  But instead of returning the server "id", I'd like to return the "name". Right now I have this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT server_id, count(server_name) AS count 
  FROM clients 
 GROUP BY server_id
```

This returns the server id instead of the name. How do I fix that? Complete beginner to SQL and mySQL by the way.

Comment: You probably want to look into [MySql Joins](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en///join.html). If this is not the answer you are looking for, you can get better answers by improving your question with some example code.

Comment: You can use an alias....or a mix of stuffs....a recommend you to make a sqlfiddle with your table structures....or show us your table structures and an example of result data(expected data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```sql
SELECT s.server_id, 
       s.server_name, 
       COUNT(*) count_clients
  FROM clients c JOIN servers s 
    ON c.server_id = s.server_id
  GROUP BY s.server_id, s.server_name
```

Output:

```
| SERVER_ID | SERVER_NAME | COUNT_CLIENTS |
-------------------------------------------
|         1 |     server1 |             2 |
|         2 |     server2 |             4 |
```

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7a87c/1)**

Comment: Thanks! It worked perfectly. I was using JOIN when trying but wasn't setting it up correctly.